# Show ECB menu item based on user permissions

Tags: ecb-menu

I am using a Delegate control to add a menu item in SharePoint Edit control block. I want to show the menu item based on two conditions.

- Versioning of the list should be enabled.
- Current user should have
  deleteListItems permissions.

I get the versioning information from the ctx object. However, since there is no way to get the permission information from ctx object, I have written JSOM for it. Following is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var context = null;
    var web = null;
    var hasPermissions = false;
    function Custom_AddListMenuItems(m, ctx) {
        CheckUserPermissions();
        if (hasPermissions) {
            AddECBMenuItems(m, ctx);
        }
    }

    function Custom_AddDocLibMenuItems(m, ctx) {
        CheckUserPermissions();
        if (hasPermissions) {
            AddECBMenuItems(m, ctx);
        }
    }

    function AddECBMenuItems(m, ctx) {
        var pageUrl = ctx.HttpRoot + "/_layouts/NY.ExportVersionHistory/ExportVersionHistory.aspx?ID=" + currentItemID + "&amp;List=" + ctx.listName;
        if (ctx.verEnabled) {
            CAMOpt(m, "Export Version History", "window.open('" + pageUrl + "');", "/_layouts/images/NY.ExportVersionHistory/Excel_Small.png");
            CAMSep(m);
        }
    }

    function CheckUserPermissions() {
        context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = context.get_web();
        context.load(web, 'EffectiveBasePermissions');
        context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
    }
    function onSuccess() {
        if (web.get_effectiveBasePermissions().has(SP.PermissionKind.deleteListItems)) {
            hasPermissions = true;
        }
    }
    function onFailure(sender, args) {
        alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + 'n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
</script>
```

Now when I log in with a user having **deleteListItems** permissions and browse to a list in which versioning is enabled and click ECB of any item, the first time it doesn't show the new ECB item **(Export Version History)** . It does show on subsequesnt ECB clicks. The problem arises because of the asynchronous behavior of the JSOM since **hasPermissions** field will be false for the first time. In ribbon we have **RefreshCommandUI()** to avert this issue. How can I fix this issue in ECB?

**UPDATE**

I also tried several other options like moving the code which checks UserPermissions to OnSuccess method, Using Promises with the JavaScript Client Object Model etc. Here is a pictorial representation of what happens when I execute the code. The ECB menu is already generated by the time the code in OnSuccess method is executed.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORE.js file has a function named `HasRights` which takes two parameters. Passing EmptyMask value of 0x0 and 0x8 for DeleteListItems fixes this. The code looks like this:

```
function Custom_AddListMenuItems(m, ctx) {
        AddECBMenuItems(m, ctx);  
    }

    function Custom_AddDocLibMenuItems(m, ctx) {
        AddECBMenuItems(m, ctx);
    }

    function AddECBMenuItems(m, ctx) {
        var pageUrl = ctx.HttpRoot + "/_layouts/NY.ExportVersionHistory/ExportVersionHistory.aspx?ID=" + currentItemID + "&amp;List=" + ctx.listName;
        if (ctx.verEnabled && HasRights(0x0, 0x8)) {
            CAMOpt(m, "Export Version History", "window.open('" + pageUrl + "');", "/_layouts/images/NY.ExportVersionHistory/Excel_Small.png");
            CAMSep(m);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of JSOM based solution I suggest alternative approach:
Use SPSecurityTrimmedControl control with properly set PermissionsString

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I resolved the particular issue  using SPSecurityTrimmedControl. However, I will keep the question open, as there can be situations where we need to use JSOM to get the info from the site, list etc. +1 from my side